# Repmgr installation and primary register

Tags: postgresql, clustering, high-availability, postgresql-13, repmgr

When I run `/usr/pgsql-13/bin/repmgr -f /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr.conf primary register` I get an error:

```
NOTICE: attempting to install extension "repmgr"
ERROR: unable to create "repmgr" extension:
  ERROR:  extension "repmgr" has no installation script nor update path for version "5.4"
```

I have this on the database for `SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = repmgr;`
[image]
and for SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name='repmgr';

[image]